# How to use linear indexes on cv::cuda::PtrStepSzf data

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I'm working with opencv 3.1 cv::cuda template matching but the `cv::cuda::minMaxLoc()` function is too slow for my case. My match results have minimum size of `128x128` and max size up to `512x512`. In average `minMaxLoc()` will take 1.65 ms for the `128x128` and up to 25 ms for something like `350x350` which is too long since this is done hundreds of times.

I underestand that my match sizes are maybe too small for what do you usually use in GPU. But I want to test along the lines that Robert Crovella did at [thrust::max_element slow in comparison cublasIsamax - More efficient implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925979/thrustmax-element-slow-in-comparison-cublasisamax-more-efficient-implementat) to see if I can get better performance.

My problem is that all those reductions the data is being read using linear indexes and `cv::cuda::PtrStepSzf`does not allow this(At least I did not find how). I try to reshape my match result but I cannot do that since the data is not contiguous. Do I need to go toward `cudaMallocPitch` and `cudaMemcpy2D`If that the case how I do that with a `cv::cuda::GPUMat` read as `cv::cuda::PtrStepSzf` object?

```
    __global__ void minLoc(const    cv::cuda::PtrStepSzf data,
                                float* minVal,
                                float * minValLoc
                        )
    {
        int dsize = data.cols*data.rows
        __shared__ volatile T   vals[nTPB];
        __shared__ volatile int idxs[nTPB];
        __shared__ volatile int last_block;
        int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        last_block = 0;
        T   my_val = FLOAT_MIN;
        int my_idx = -1;
        // sweep from global memory
        while (idx < dsize)
        {
            //data(idx) is an illegal call;The legal one is data(x,y)
            // How do I do it?
            if (data(idx) > my_val) 
            {
                my_val = data(idx); my_idx = idx;
            }
                idx += blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
        }

                // ... rest of the kernel
    }   

   void callMinLocKernel(cv::InputArray _input,       
                cv::Point minValLoc,
                float minVal,
                cv::cuda::Stream _stream)
    {
        const cv::cuda::GpuMat input = _input.getGpuMat();
        dim3 cthreads(32, 32);
        dim3 cblocks(
            static_cast<int>(std::ceil(input1.size().width /
                static_cast<double>(cthreads.x))),
            static_cast<int>(std::ceil(input1.size().height / 
                static_cast<double>(cthreads.y))));

        // code that creates and upload d_min, d_minLoc
        float h_min    = 9999;
        int h_minLoc   = -1;
        float * d_min  = 0;
        int * d_minLoc = 0;
        //gpuErrchk is defined on other place
        gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_min, sizeof(h_min)));
        gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_minLoc, sizeof(h_minLoc));
        gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(d_min, &h_min, sizeof(h_min), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
        gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(d_minLoc, &h_minLoc, sizeof(h_minLoc), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

        cudaStream_t stream = cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(_stream);
        minLoc<<<cblocks, cthreads, 0, stream>>>(input,d_min,d_minLoc);
        gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
        //code to read the answer
        gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(&h_min, d_min, sizeof(h_min), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
        gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(&h_minLoc, d_minLoc, sizeof(h_minLoc), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

        minValLoc = cv::point(h_minLoc/data.cols,h_minLoc%data.cols)
        minVal = h_min;     
    }

    int main()
    {
        //read Background and template
        cv::Mat input = imread("cat.jpg",0);
        cv::Mat templ = imread("catNose.jpg",0)

        //convert to floats
        cv::Mat float_input, float_templ;
        input.convertTo(float_input,CV_32FC1);
        input.convertTo(float_templ,CV_32FC1);

        //upload Bckg and template to gpu
        cv::cuda::GpuMat d_src,d_templ, d_match;
        Size size = float_input.size();
        d_src.upload(float_input);
        d_templ.upload(float_templ);


        double min_val, max_val;
        Point min_loc, max_loc;   

        Ptr<cv::cuda::TemplateMatching> alg = cuda::createTemplateMatching(d_src.type(), CV_TM_SQDIFF);
        alg->match(d_src, d_templ, d_match);
        cv::cuda::Normalize(d_match,d_match);
        //Too slow
        //cv::cuda::minMaxLoc(d_match, &min_val, &max_val, &min_loc, &max_loc);

        callMinLocKernel(d_match,min_val,min_loc);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way to actually use linear indexes with `cv::cuda::PtrStepSzf`. I am not sure there is one. Looks like when this format is used it can only use 2 subscripts. Instead I used the pointer `ptr` on `cv::cuda::GpuMat input` variable in the kernel wrapper as follow:

```
#define nTPB 1024
#define FLOAT_MAX 9999.0f
void callMinLocKernel(cv::InputArray _input,       
        cv::Point minValLoc,
        float minVal,
        cv::cuda::Stream _stream)
{
    const cv::cuda::GpuMat input = _input.getGpuMat();
    const float* linSrc = input.ptr<float>();
    size_t step         = input.step;
    dim3 cthreads(nTPB);
    dim3 cblocks(
    static_cast<int>(std::ceil(input.size().width*input1.size().height /
        static_cast<double>(nTPB))));

    // code that creates and upload d_min, d_minLoc
    float h_min    = 9999;
    int h_minLoc   = -1;
    float * d_min  = 0;
    int * d_minLoc = 0;
    //gpuErrchk is defined on other place
    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_min, sizeof(h_min)));
    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_minLoc, sizeof(h_minLoc));
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(d_min, &h_min, sizeof(h_min), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(d_minLoc, &h_minLoc, sizeof(h_minLoc), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    cudaStream_t stream = cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(_stream);
    minLoc<<<cblocks, cthreads, 0, stream>>>(input,d_min,d_minLoc);
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    //code to read the answer
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(&h_min, d_min, sizeof(h_min), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(&h_minLoc, d_minLoc, sizeof(h_minLoc), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    minValLoc = cv::point(h_minLoc/data.cols,h_minLoc%data.cols)
    minVal = h_min;
}
```

And inside the Kernel as:

```
__global__ void minLoc(const float* data,
                       const size_t step,
                       cv::Size dataSz,
                       float* minVal,
                       float * minValLoc
                    )
{

    __shared__ volatile T   vals[nTPB];
    __shared__ volatile int idxs[nTPB];
    __shared__ volatile int last_block;

    int idx         = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    const int dsize = dataSz.height*dataSz.width;
    last_block = 0;
    float  my_val = FLOAT_MAX;
    int my_idx = -1;
    // sweep from global memory
    while (idx < dsize)
    {
        int row = idx / dataSz.width;
        int id = ( row*step / sizeof( float ) ) + idx % dataSz.width;
        if ( data[id] < my_val )
        {
           my_val = data[id];
           my_idx = idx;
        }
        idx += blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    }

            // ... rest of the kernel
}
```

The `step` is in bytes so it needs to be divided by `sizeof(typeVariable)`
I hope this help!